# How can i upload multiple files from local system to AWS S3 bucket Using Aws Lambda Functions?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I just want to upload files from local system to aws s3 bucket by using AWS Lambda Function. So i can put trigger or can schedule it to pull data automatically?

I try different examples bit not worth it.

Comment: No, Lamba obviously has no access to your local file system. You need to upload the files to S3, not the Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it using Lambda. You must use the cli or a function running on your local machine to upload the files to S3:

Cli example

```
aws s3 cp ./localfile.txt s3://my-bucket/my-prefix/
```

[Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html)